# Ruby modify a piece of a string

Tags: ruby, string

Totally new to Ruby. This is a simple homework assignment. The secret_code function needs to take in input string and perform the following actions:

1. In the first block of letters before a space, capitalize all but the first char
2. Reverse the string

So if the input were "super duper", the output should be "repud REPUs".

I coded the function as follows:

```
def secret_code(input) 
  input.split(" ").first[1..-1].each_char do |i|
    input[i] = i.upcase
  end
  return input.reverse
end
```

It passes the unit tests, but I am wondering if there is a better way to code it. Is it possible to avoid using the loop? I tried

```
return input.split(" ").first[1..-1].upcase.reverse
```

But that didn't quite work. Any thoughts on how to clean this up are appreciated!

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @RubyLovely He told you that. Read the question.

Comment: Refer to the question. If the input were "this is input", the output should be "tupni si SIHt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
def secret_code(input)
  first_space = input.index(' ')
  (input[0] + input[1...first_space].upcase + input[first_space..-1]).reverse
end
```

Note that in Ruby, the last expression evaluate in a method is always returned, so you can omit the final `return`.

Comment: See discussion of explicit `return` here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby

Answer (score 8):

```
"super duper".sub(/(?<=.)\S+/, &:upcase).reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "super duper"

words = s.split(' ')
words.first[1..-1] = words.first[1..-1].upcase
words.each { |word| word.reverse! }
s = words.reverse.join(' ')
puts s # => repud REPUs
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily any better, but sure, it can be done without a loop...

```
def f x
  (b = [(a = x.split)[0].upcase, *a.drop(1)].join(' ').reverse)[-1] = x[0, 1]
  return b
end
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can try the below:*

```
a = "super duper"
p a.gsub(a.split[0...1].join(' '),a.split[0...1].join(' ').capitalize.swapcase).reverse
```

***Output:***

```
"repud REPUs"
```