# How to make a Ruby function act like an explicit 'return' statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something sort of unusual with a Ruby method.  I'd like to make *terminate* act like an explicit return statement in the below code:

```
def terminate(data)
  data.upcase
  #I want to put a command somewhere in this scope
end

def other_method
  data = "cow"
  terminate data
  data = "fox"
end

other_method

#Desired response
#> "COW"
#Actual response in everything that we try
#> "fox"
```

I want other_method to return "COW".  Specifically, by causing 'terminate' to function as an explicit return statement.  Is there something I can throw / raise that will do this?  Or some other hacky way I can force this behavior?

---

Currently, in our code we always use (many, many instances of this across a large codebase, with frequent changes to it):

```
return foo! param1, param2
return foo2! param1, param2
return foo3! param1, param2
```

We'd like to replace this with:

```
foo! param1, param2
foo1! param1, param2
foo2! param1, param2
```

There is no other way foo! is used in our code base by design.  It's basically syntactic sugar.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. [Ruby does have an explicit `return` keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/), which is used when you need to return early (implicit return is mostly preferred otherwise). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby

Comment: You might need to explain your usecase better; why can't you just return?

Comment: You shouldn't force the calling function to return prematurely unless you're throwing an exception. What you're asking for here is a redefinition of how Ruby and many other programming languages work.

Comment: No idea what you're really trying to do, but there is a huge code smell here. This will be incredibly fragile code.

Comment: Unfortunately Ruby is nothing like Visual Basic where you can assign the return value through the method or function's name like `other_method = terminate(data)`. If that's something you're trying to find then you should give it up.

Comment: Everybody, don't close the question as unclear when it is a completely clear request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

throw/catch will do this.

Wrap the guts of your method in a call to [Kernel#catch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-catch):

```
def something
  catch :return do
    foo! 123, 456
  end
end
```

Have `#foo!` call [Kernel#throw](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-throw):

```
def foo!(*args)
  throw :return, args
end
```

When #throw is called, it causes an exception which is caught by the #catch statement.  The result of the #catch statement is then the value that was given to the #throw statement.  Therefore:

```
p something     # [123, 456]
```

If #throw is not called, then the result of the #catch is the result of the last statement executed in its block.

Comment: @Boris, I think your edit would be better as its own answer.  It's not bad (it may be better!), but it completely changes what I wrote.

Comment: Wayne, certain sort of people closed the question as "unclear", so I cannot add an answer until they reopen it. Because I didn't want to keep watching if they already reopened it or not, I simply edited the answer that was closest to my suggestion. Could you merge my answer into yours rather than simply reverting the edit?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I don't think that's appropriate.  Best would be if the question is re-opened.  I've voted to do so.

Comment: Best would be if people don't close the questions just because _they_ cannot understand them.

Comment: If you do not accept my radical edit, I'll at least upvote you for bringing up `catch` and `throw`, the proper tools for the job. They have been [dissed and compared to goto](http://m.onkey.org/ruby-i-don-t-like-2-catch-wtf-throw-wtf), but they do have their place exactly in situations like this.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky You are a gentleman and a scholar.  Thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, unless you use an explicit `return` statement elsewhere in your method, the last line executed in your method is what's returned.  Maybe the complexity is getting lost in your simpler example, but: can you store the result of `terminate` in a variable and return that?

```
def other_method
  data = "cow"
  result = terminate data
  data = "fox"
  result
end
```

Comment: Updated question with details on reasoning.  Basically, we have a huge variety of functions that are built with business logic, and we'd like business users, rather than needing to type 'return' in their scripts followed by a formatting command, to be able to type: foo1! data, foo2! data, etc for simplicity of our DSL.

Comment: @Oeste I think making your business users write Ruby (even Ruby that has been DSLed beyond recognition) is a mistake. Ruby is littered with strange sharp edges for programmer novices let alone non-programmers. I think you'd be better off writing your own language or using an existing language that is aimed at non-programmers.

Comment: Alex, I presume you mean "fox".

Answer (score 3):

> In Ruby, unless you use an explicit return statement elsewhere in your
>   method, the last line of your method is what's returned.

That's incorrect.

> Actual response in everything that we try => "fox"

A ruby method without an explicit return statement returns the result of the last statement that *was executed*.  Here is the last statement that executes in your method:

```
data = "fox"
```

And the "result" of an assignment statement is the right hand side, so your method returns 'fox'.  Your method will ALWAYS return 'fox' if that line is always the last line that executes in your method.

**Response to comment:**

You could do this(but I don't see how it will help you):

```
def other_method
  data = "cow"

  func = Proc.new {|data| return data.upcase}
  func[data]

  data = "fox"
end

puts other_method

--output:--
COW
```

But you can't do this:

```
def other_method(func)
  data = "cow"

  func[data]

  data = "fox"
end

f = Proc.new { |data| return data.upcase }
other_method(f)

--output:--
unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
```

...

```
Is there something I can throw / raise that will do this?
```

Yes, you can do this:

```
class MyTerminateMethodError < Exception
end

def terminate(d)
  raise MyTerminateMethodError, d.upcase
end


def other_method
  data = "cow"
  terminate data
  data = "fox"
rescue MyTerminateMethodError => result
  result   #This is the last statement to execute, so result is returned
end

puts other_method

--output:--
COW
```

But the thing of it is, there's no benefit to passing data to the terminate() method, because you can do this:

```
class MyTerminateMethodError < Exception
end

def terminate
  raise MyTerminateMethodError
end

def other_method
  data = "cow"
  terminate 
  data = "fox"
rescue MyTerminateMethodError
  data.upcase
end

puts other_method
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
class MyTerminateMethodError < Exception
end

def other_method
  data = "cow"
  raise MyTerminateMethodError
  data = "fox"
rescue MyTerminateMethodError
  data.upcase
end

puts other_method
```

Which can be written more efficiently as:

```
def other_method
  data = "cow"
  return data.upcase
  data = "fox"
end
```

Okay, but you want different behavior to be applied to data--not just upcase()?  How about a block?

```
def other_method
  data = "cow"

  if block_given?
    return (yield data)
  end

  data = "fox"
end

result = other_method { |x| x.capitalize }
puts result  =>Cow
```

If you can't change other_method(), then you could do it like this:

```
class MyTerminateMethodError < Exception
end

def terminate(d)
  raise MyTerminateMethodError, d.upcase
end


def other_method
  data = "cow"
  terminate data
  data = "fox"
end

result = begin 
  other_method
rescue MyTerminateMethodError => str 
end

puts result   #=>COW
```

Comment: What we want is for the called method to act as an explicit return statement.

Comment: @Oeste: Okay, I understand what you want.  But method calls in your code are replaced by the method's return value, and a method cannot return a return statement.  However, a return statement in a Proc will return from a surrounding def, but I don't see how that will help you...but I'll post an example.

Comment: Good spot on the "last line *executed*" error in my post - thanks. I've updated it to be more accurate.