# Ruby explicit & implicit return confusions

Tags: ruby, methods, scope, return

I am playing building a little address book program. I have three classes; `AddressBook`, `Contact` and `Address`. A `to_s` method written in the `Address` class defines the output format of an address and I have written a `print_addresses` method in the `Contact` class which pending on whether the argument passed in is `long` or `short` should output one of two output formats as defined in the to_s method. When calling `print_addresses('long')` on a `Contact` instance from the `AddressBook` class it will only output the `short` format as defined in the `to_s` method.

This is not working as I expected and i'm pretty sure it's fault with my understanding of method and variable scope or explicit and implicit returns, but I cannot discern where I am going wrong. The code I've written is below, can anyone help me understand this better? Thank you.

**Address Class**

```
class Address
  attr_accessor :kind, :street_1, :street_2, :city, :state, :postal_code 


  def to_s(format = 'short')
    address = ''
    case format
    when 'long'
      address += street_1 + "\n"
      address += street_2 + "\n" if !street_2.nil? 
      address += "#{city}, #{state} #{postal_code}"
    when 'short'
      address += "#{kind}: "
      address += street_1
      if street_2 
        address += " " + street_2 
      end
      address += ", #{city}, #{state}, #{postal_code}"
    end
    address
   end
  end
```

**Contact Class**

```
require './phone_number'
require './address'

class Contact
  attr_writer :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name
  attr_reader :phone_numbers, :addresses

  def initialize
    @phone_numbers = []
    @addresses = []
  end

def add_address(kind, street_1, street_2, city, state, postal_code)
    address = Address.new
    address.kind = kind
    address.street_1 = street_1
    address.street_2 = street_2
    address.city = city
    address.state = state
    address.postal_code = postal_code
    addresses.push(address)
end

def print_addresses(format = 'short')
    puts "Addresses:"
    case format
    when 'short' 
      addresses.each do |address|
        address.to_s('short')
      end
    when 'long'
      addresses.each do |address|
        address.to_s('long')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**AddressBook Class**

```
require './contact'

class AddressBook
  attr_reader :contacts

  def initialize
    @contacts = []
  end

  def find_by_name(name)
    results = []
    search = name.downcase
    @contacts.each do |contact|
      if contact.first_name.downcase.include?(search)
        results.push(contact)
      end
    end
    puts "Name search results (#{search})"
    results.each do |contact|
      puts contact.to_s('full_name')
      puts contact.print_addresses('long')
      puts contact.print_phone_numbers

    end
  end
end

address_book = AddressBook.new

james = Contact.new
james.first_name = "James"
james.middle_name = "jim"
james.last_name = "jimbo"
james.add_address('home', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5')



address_book.contacts.push(james)
puts "-" * 35
puts james.print_addresses('long')
puts '=' * 35
```

**ruby address_book.rb - Output**

```
------------------------------
Addresses:
home: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
===================================
```

Was expecting and trying to achieve:

```
------------------------------
Addresses:
1,
2,
3, 4, 5
===================================
```

Comment: Missing `end` of `def add_address`

Comment: `Contact.add_phone_number` is never defined.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks Aetherus, paste error. Not solved cited issue.

Comment: Thanks Schwern, tried to take out irrelevant methods but left some trace by mistake, trace now removed!

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Did your code raise any errors?

Comment: I was expecting the output defined in the `when 'long'` case of the `Address.to_s` method, but I only get the output of the `when 'short'` case even though i pass in `'long'` to `print_addresses`.

Comment: No errors, just only outputs the `'short'` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing both the long and short versions. You can see this by adding a `puts "long"` and `puts "short"` in your `to_s` function.

The problem is not about scope, but your reliance on the implicit return of the last evaluated expression in `print_addresses`.  `print_addresses` doesn't print anything and it doesn't explicitly return anything.  It dutifully calls `address.to_s('long')`, throws out the result, and returns the result of the last evaluated expression... `address`. `address` is then run through `puts` which results in it being converted to a string with the default short format.  You can comment out the call to `address.to_s` and you'll get the same result.

This might seem weird that `address` is the last evaluated expression which is why you should **always do an explicit return**. It makes the code easier to read and saves everyone a lot of headaches. This also points out that your function is supposed to return more than one thing, something you can't easily do implicitly.

```
  def print_addresses(format = 'short')
    puts "Addresses:"

    formatted_addresses = []

    case format
    when 'short' 
      addresses.each do |address|
        formatted_addresses << address.to_s('short')
      end
    when 'long'
      addresses.each do |address|
        formatted_addresses << address.to_s('long')
      end
    end

    return formatted_addresses
  end
```

As a side note, since `print_addresses` doesn't print it should be called `format_addresses`. It should also get rid of that redundant case statement. The bit of extra formatting (the "Address" header) goes into a wrapper method to leave `format_addresses` flexible.

```
  def display_addresses(format)
    return ["Addresses: "] + format_addresses(format)
  end

  def format_addresses(format = 'short')    
    formatted_addresses = []

    addresses.each do |address|
      formatted_addresses << address.to_s(format)
    end

    return formatted_addresses
  end
```

Comment: Bow to thee @Schwern, thank you indeed. I've been starring at this conundrum for many hours trying to get my head around it, you have officially shown me the light. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I scratched my head over it for a while myself and spent probably a half hour with debugging `puts` and in the debugger puzzling it out.

Comment: Thank you Schwerm, very helpful. I wonder is there a rule you observe in terms of when to explicitly return and when to reply on an implicit return?

Think I'll re-title this question so people with return problems can find it more easily!

Comment: @jbk I do have a rule. **Always use an explicit return**. One extra word will save you or somebody else hours of debugging. An empty return makes it explicit that the function returns nothing and it avoids people later using an accidental return value. The exception would be very small inline functions like `array.map { |x| x*2 }`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip @Schwern. Explicit returning 'breaks' from a function does it not, so perhaps one would have to be careful with its use in, for example, a loop where you could want to continue looping?

Comment: @jbk Yes. To terminate a block or loop use a [`break`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement). Here are [other people's opinions on explicit return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby).