# How do I compare elements of separate arrays at specific indexes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

I have two arrays, I want to return the larger number from the same position in each array.

```
def get_larger_numbers(a, b)
c = []
count = 0
    while count < 10 #assumes there are less than 10 elements in an array, not an ideal solution.
        if a[count] > b[count]
            c << a[count]
        elsif b[count] > a[count]
            c << b[count]
        else #if numbers are the same
            c << a[count]
        end
    count+= 1
    end
return c
end

 a = [13, 64, 15, 17, 88]
 b = [23, 14, 53, 17, 80]
```

should return:
    c == [23, 64, 53, 17, 88]

Clearly, my code doesn't work, what's the best way to refer to increasing index positions?

Also interested to know simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: Will you ever have two arrays of different size passed in? What should happen in that case? Is the output array the shorter length, or does it contain the unpaired elements of the larger input array?

Comment: @DanielStevens: that was my question too. Regardless, it should only iterate through the smaller array, as nil comparisons would raise error.

Comment: An error might be desirable if the code is not expected to compare arrays of unequal length.

Comment: Sure, but that's not scalable. A good programmer should ensure that his code won't throw nasty/unwanted errors **ever**.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because of the static `10` you have as the length. Instead I suggest you make your code more dynamic with regards to how often you loop.

```
def get_larger_numbers(a,b)
  c = []

  [a.length, b.length].min.times do |i|
    if a[i] > b[i]
      c << a[i]
    else
      c << b[i]
    end
  end

  c
end

a = [13, 64, 15, 17, 88]
b = [23, 14, 53, 17, 80]

get_larger_numbers(a,b)
#=> [23, 64, 53, 17, 88]
```

This solution assumes that if the arrays are not equal size, you want to throw the rest away.

Comment: imho, a `for` loop may be better because it's more obvious that you're starting at 0 and working up to the last element in the array... but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... Here's what you **should** do:

```
def get_larger_numbers(a, b)
  c = [] #declare empty array for answer
  for i in 0...(a.length < b.length ? a.length : b.length) #see EDIT note
    c << (a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i])
  end
  c #this is an implicit return
end

 a = [13, 64, 15, 17, 88]
 b = [23, 14, 53, 17, 80]

puts get_larger_numbers(a,b)
```

This'll do a `for` loop that'll run from 0 to the length of `a`. Yes, it assumes that they're the same length. I figure this is what you want.

Anyway, there's a simple ternary that compares the value of each element in both arrays, one index at a time.

It'll push the bigger value to the `c` array, leaving you with the greater values in the `c` array to be returned.

EDIT: Added the ternary expression so that `for` loops through only the smaller array, because comparing with nil (which is what is at any n index beyond the array, presumably) would raise an error.

Comment: You can get rid of the `-1` fix to the for loop is you use the end point exclusive range format `...` instead of `..`.

Comment: You can use the ternary operator in the loop body to cut down on the code bulk. Why not, if you're already using it to construct the range for the `for` loop.

Comment: @DanielStevens I added the ternary later. I was being lazy when I put it in, as I know beginners don't usually understand ternary at first. I used `if/else` only to make it simpler to understand... I'll edit for `...`.

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution would be:

```
def get_larger_numbers(a, b)
    return a.zip(b).map{|x, y| (x >= y) ? x : y } # Return optional, added for clarity
end

a = [13, 64, 15, 17, 88]
b = [23, 14, 53, 17, 80]

p get_larger_numbers(a, b)
```

Note that this assumes the input arrays are of the same length. If arrays are of unequal length, you can truncate to the length of the shorter array, or pad the end with the unpaired elements of the larger array. The current code will throw an error, letting you know you've hit this unspecified case.

As for how it works, the `zip` pairs the elements of the two arrays, so `a.zip(b)` becomes:

```
[[13, 23], [64, 14], [15, 53], [17, 17], [88, 80]]
```

It then loops over the array with `map` to produce a new array, passing each pair into the block, which returns the larger of the two elements to fill the output array.

Comment: Great, but you want this to be simple enough to understand. What's the point of a one-liner in a 7-line program?

Comment: Is the keyword _return_ necessary? Perhaps you are making the code more explicit. Nice answer btw!

Comment: You're right, it's not needed. I am generally explicit with return. I like to be clear when functions are expected to return a value rather than just perform a side effect which may not return a value.

Comment: Well, @DanielStevens, if your function is of the `void` variety you should just return `nil` implicitly or explicitly on the last line. No need to **ever** be explicit on returns in Ruby. I've talked with a few people and the common mindset is that explicit `return` in Ruby is either redundant or not-best practice.

Comment: Explanation makes it so much better. +1

Comment: What would be the objection to an explicit `return`? For one, it can be used to reduce the number of levels of nested `if`s, which I think can make the code easier to follow.

Comment: @CarySwoveland in `if`s or `return if`s sure, but not really at the end of the function, is what I am saying.

Comment: I've tried things both ways with return, and found code is generally more clear when it was included. It prevents people from modifying the last line of a function and not realizing they were also changing a return value. It happened at work a few times when return was omitted. I've seen at least one article that suggests being explicit with return as a good practice, but I have no idea how widespread agreement is on the matter.

Comment: Daniel, I confess I've never written Ruby for money, but of all the Ruby code I've read in books and articles, I've *never*--not once--seen `return` included when it's not needed. Some readers of your code may draw the erroneous conclusion that you don't realize that `return` in the last line of a method is not needed (as they have here), and that you may therefore be relatively inexperienced with the language. If that's not a problem, go ahead and stick it in (except, perhaps, when  applying for a job).

Comment: I suppose I can at least make a note of it, considering how much contention it has caused.

Comment: As for a question specifically on using return, see [Is it good style to explicitly return in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby). It seems many people appreciate the clarity of intent.

Comment: The result would have been no different. They're not contentious issues at all. You can do what you want, but some Rubiests--some coders generally--would rather have a root canal than be forced to write code that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two arrays are the same size, simply:

```
def largest_by_position(a,b)
  a.zip(b).map(&:max)
end

largest_by_position([13, 64, 15, 17, 88], [23, 14, 53, 17, 80])
  #=> [23, 64, 53, 17, 88]
```

Alternatively, make the operative line:

```
[a,b].transpose.map(&:max)
```

For equal-size arrays `a` and `b`, [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) always have this [yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang) relationship:

```
a.zip(b) == [a,b].transpose #=> true
```