# Ruby on Rails - Changing TRUE to ACTIVE from model or controller instead of view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, haml

In my `companies` database, I have a **status** column - `boolean` *(true or false)*. Is it possible to change **true** to **active** & **false** to **inactive** from model or controller instead of view templates.

This is what I currently use in my view templates:

```
- if company.status == true
  %p Active
- else
  %p Inactive
```

I feel these are just unnecessary conditions and I am looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: You can define a function to do this checking and to set the status to Active or Inactive in your model and you can call that method each time when you want to check and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An addendum to the previous answers : putting a view concern in the model isn't best practice - it violates SRP. Of course you won't be struck by  lightning for that little sin, however you should be aware of that.

Also the alternative would be to keep this basic logic in the view like so with a common  one-liner :

```
%p= company.status ? "Active" : "Inactive"
```

Or finally put it in a helper :

```
%p= boolean_to_activity( company.status )

# ... in helpers/some_helper.rb

def boolean_to_activity status
  status ? "Active" : "Inactive"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me the best practice. Is it any way I can pass the Values (Active, Inactive) with a style inside a <span>?

Comment: yes but you must use raw so rails doesn't escape the tags : `raw("<span class='active'>Active</span>") : raw("<span..)`

Answer (score 0):

In your Company model, define a function like this.

```
def get_status
  return self.status ? "Active" : "Inactive"
end
```

In your view, you can simply do this.

```
<%= company.get_status %>
```

Comment: Yes this was what  I was talking about :)

Comment: Thanks Harry. I get the function, but could you please explain how it works so I ca learn from it :) Tnx

Comment: Its simple. `get_status` is an instance method which can be called from any `Company` instance. the function simply checks the instance's status, if its true then it returns active otherwise inactive. So if you do `company = Company.first` then `company` is an instance and when you call the method `get_status`, it simply checks its `status`, if its true or false and return accordingly. Hope its clear.

Comment: @Harry Bomrah you could remove `return` method as in ruby last line is a return value .

Comment: As you are saying _you are always stick to a coding pattern._ And I would like to say this is a pattern in ruby that not to use return as a last line in method

Comment: @Vinay just for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change true to active & false to inactive from
>   model or controller instead of view templates.

Yes It is possible

You could write a `instance method` at your model level to make the view code **`DRY`**

On following  [Harry Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741129/3098330) in more abstract way we could write !!!

```
def get_status
 status ? "Active" : "Inactive"
end
```