# A method for creating a huge number

Tags: ruby, literals

RubyMonk makes a point on how you can use underscores for convenience to write large numbers that can become difficult to read without demarcation.

Their task is: Try using underscores to make a huge, readable number. They provide this code:

```
def describe(something)
  puts "I am a: #{something.class} and I look like: #{something}"
end

def big_num
  # create a huge number
end

describe(big_num)
```

Could anyone explain how I would go about creating a huge number? According to the error messages below, I have to use underscores in the code to make it pass.

Comment: `1000 == 1_000`, so `1_000_000_000`... This is the underscore notation Ruby allows us to use (for convenience).

Comment: Uh. `Bignum` and `Fixnum` are implementation-speficic optimizations, they really shouldn't be taught in a Ruby course at all, especially not to beginners. Ruby only guarantees that there is an `Integer` class, and it allows for, but does not require nor specify, one or many implementation-specific subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RubyMonk expects a object of class [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Bignum.html), which is part of the standard Ruby library. From the documentation:

> Bignum objects hold integers outside the range of Fixnum. Bignum
>   objects are created automatically when integer calculations would
>   otherwise overflow a Fixnum.

So you just have to create a number that is bigger than what Fixnum can handle. For example, this will pass RubyMonk's spec:

```
def big_num
  5_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
end
```

Because the number is bigger than Fixnum can handle, Ruby automagically returns a Bignum instead. For example, try running this:

```
5_000_000_000.class
# => Fixnum
5_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.class
# => Bignum
```

Comment: I tried simply writing 1_000_000_000 inside the method. RubyMonk returns these errors 1)is a Bignum 2) RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError 3) expected 1000000000 to be a kind of Bignum –

Comment: @newbie RubyMonk expects an object of class Bignum. I explained what is happening in my edited response.

Comment: @newbie By the way, welcome to SO. Be sure to mark whichever answer you believe is the best solution to your question as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby allows you to put underscores while writing literal numbers so that large numbers can be easier to read.

The convention goes that you shouldn't put underscores if the number is 4 or less digits long and on every three numbers if it's longer, starting from right:

```
10_000_000 # => 10000000
```

Works for floating numbers too:

```
10_000.0 # => 10000.0
```

The underscores are ignored by the interpreter if you put them between two digits:

```
1_2_3_4_5 # => 12345
```

---

After looking at the error message, it is clear that RubyMonk expects `Bignum`. This is another magic, which the interpreter does transparently - if the number is small enough to be mapped to the architecture's int, the number is an instance of `Fixnum`:

```
100.class # => Fixnum
```

If that is not the case, Ruby automagically uses a dedicated class (`Bignum`):

```
(10_000_000**100).class # => Bignum
  # 10_000_000 to the power of 100, 
  # which is a very big number and
  # thus stored in Bignum
```

Comment: I tried simply writing 1_000_000_000 inside the method. RubyMonk returns these errors 1)is a Bignum
2) RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
3) expected 1000000000 to be a kind of Bignum

Answer (score 2):

Ruby allows using underscores as placeholders (i.e. they are only to increase readability for humans and are otherwise ignored). So your `big_num` method can simply have one line:

```
return 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
```

And calling that will return `1000000000000000000000000000000000`

(the `return` keyword is optional)

Comment: why would you recommend using optional `return` here knowing (hopefully) that it is not conventional?

Comment: The OP seems new to Ruby, so they may or may not be aware that Ruby will return the value without the explicit `return`. Including it makes it clear(er) what the line is doing (particularly if OP's background is in languages that require it), the parenthetical points out it's optional so if they didn't already know that they do now. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby for an interesting discussion on using vs not using it - regardless of convention.