# Ruby: Are there any situations where the return keyword is necessary?

Tags: ruby, return

In Ruby it seems we can always get by without the use of the keyword return like:

```
def abc
  #some calculations
  a = x + some_stuff
end
```

And `abc` will return whatever the last expression evaluates, here it will be (x + some_stuff). So are there any situations where the use of return is necessary, or compulsory? Is there some situation where the use of return keyword would make(or has made) the the answer to a problem more graceful?

Comment: I think my question differs from what was asked earlier. I edited it trying to further clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many number of cases where `return` will come handy. The important point is it allows you to break out of your method, which you cannot do with your example. One such example

```
def abc
 # do some stuff
 return result if desired_flag
 raise "undesired"
end
```

In the above example, in ideal cases the method will always return some value. However if that does not happen, it will raise an error.

Comment: How is it better than `raise "undesired" unless desired_flag ; result`?

Comment: @mudasobwa what if you need to do some other calculations or update instance variables or log or perform a combination of all these before raising error?

Comment: Again I know even those things can be done in multiple other ways, maybe create a different method, but its just an example I can come up for using return.

Comment: Early `return` makes sense as a very first line of the method. That’s why, apparently, it’s called _early_ return.

Answer (score -1):

These are a few situations where I feel return would be useful.
1) When using a particular construct, where the construct has a default return value, but you wish to return something else.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each do |element|
  return element if x.include?(element ** 3)
end
```

2) When you want to break out of your method like.

```
def some_func
  return nil if failed_some_early_check
  # function code 
  @answer     # returns the list
end
```

3) For documentation purposes.

4) When you are writing a procedural method, where the side effect of the method is important than the returned value, in fact to keep people from (ab)using an intermediary state value, you have to return nil(there are off course other ways of doing this.)

```
def side_effect
  #computations on private stuff
  return nil
end
```

.....but in none of these cases is it compulsory to use return.

Comment: Aware of the fact, that `return` actually returns from the surrounding method, not only from lambda. For your first example it’s better to use `break element`.

Comment: `return` in the last line contradicts all ruby style guides. Use `nil` instead of `return nil` in the last line.

Comment: I do not understand what “3) for documentation purposes” means. That said, there is only one correct meaningful example of early return (2) and it is an exact copy of the answer by @shivam. Downvoted.

Comment: I type slowly, so I was still typing my answer when @shivam posted, just trying to document an answer. I am new to ruby(only 10 days) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby) I felt like some more experienced people were talking.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I marked OP as duplicate.