# Multi-Threaded Merge Sort

Tags: ruby, multithreading, algorithm, sorting, concurrency

How does this get **implemented** in Ruby? Particularly, how do the results of the spawned threads get returned to the main thread?

```
def merge_sort(array)
  return array if base_case?(array)

  first_half, second_half = split_into_halves(array)

  # spawn recursive calls
  first_spawn = Thread.new {
    sorted_first_half  = merge_sort(first_half)
  }

  second_spawn = Thread.new {
    sorted_second_half = merge_sort(second_half)
  }

  # sync
  first_spawn.join
  second_spawn.join

  merge(sorted_first_half, sorted_second_half)
end
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but it would seem that the last statement should be return merge(...) , or array = merge(...), then return array. I'm also assuming base_case means array size < 2.

Comment: Yes, base_case means array.size < 2. My thought was that #join was Ruby's attempt at merging threads. The final line of Ruby code is returned automatically, @rcgldr

Comment: The syntax at the end seems strange. There's no return array specified for merge(...), so why should it return its result in array? The merge_sort function just returns, unlike the start where the function specifically returns array.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation of parallel [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in Ruby. Tested in Ruby 2.3.x.

```
module ParallelMergeSort

  def merge_sorted
    return self if size <= 1

    split = size / 2

    # Divide into sub-threads
    part_a, part_b = [
        Thread.new { self.slice(0, split).merge_sorted },
        Thread.new { self.slice(split, self.size - split).merge_sorted }
    ].map(&:join).map(&:value)

    # Conquer and return
    array = self.class.new
    off_a, off_b = [0, 0]

    while off_a < part_a.size && off_b < part_b.size
      a, b = part_a[off_a], part_b[off_b]

      if a <= b
        array << a
        off_a += 1
      else
        array << b
        off_b += 1
      end
    end

    while off_a < part_a.size
      array << part_a[off_a]
      off_a += 1
    end

    while off_b < part_b.size
      array << part_b[off_b]
      off_b += 1
    end

    array
  end
end
```

Since it is implemented as Ruby module, you can include it to Array class:

```
Array.send(:include, ParallelMergeSort)


[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 33, 4, 33, 44, 1, 100, 87].merge_sorted #=> [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 33, 33, 44, 87, 100]
```

Back to your question. If look closely at the line mentioning threads. I create two new [Threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Thread.html) inside new Array, do computation inside them then I [#join()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Thread.html#method-i-join) threads together and retrive [#value()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Thread.html#method-i-value) from them. Since there are always two threads in Array it I can then unpack results into variables `part_a` and `part_b`.

Comment: Please have in mind, that this is not final solution. In the real world you can't create infinite new [threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Thread.html). In real world you would have to introduce something like [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Queue.html) to your solution and possibly wait for some threads to finish execution before creating new ones. There is also [Ruby's GIL limitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) that you can eventually run into - but that is another chapter altogether. :)