# Regex to capture words before and after a target in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Assuming we have a text:

> In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the **start** of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory.

What I am trying to do is find 2 words before and after a specific word (target). So for example if target is word **start** it should match '`at`' '`the`' (left) and '`of`' '`the`' (right). I am using the following method in ruby but it returns no matches. Any tips about what to fix in my regex? I have also tried "`#{target}`" instead of `Regex.escape`.

```
    def checkWords(target, text, numLeft = 2, numRight = 2)

        regex = ""
        regex += " (\\S+) " * numLeft
        regex += Regexp.escape(target)
        regex += " (\\S+)" * numRight

        pattern = Regexp.new(regex, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
        matches = pattern.match(text)

        return true if matches
    end
```

Edit:

Regex printed:

```
(\S+)  (\S+) "£52" (\S+) (\S+)
```

Edit based on Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
def checkWords(target, text, numLeft = 2, numRight = 2)

pattern = Regexp.new(/#{"(\\S+) "*numLeft}#{Regexp.escape(target)}#{" (\\S+)"*numRight}/i)
matches = pattern.match(text)

end
```

Comment: You should log the value of `regex` and add it to your question

Comment: You have spaces doubled around `(\\S+)`. Use `regex += "(\\S+) " * numLeft` .

Comment: included the print of my regex

Comment: What is the Ruby version? Does it work well with Unicode?

Comment: Repace `Regexp.new(/#{"(\\S+) "*numLeft}#{Regexp.escape(target)}#{" (\\S+)"*numRight}/i)` with `/#{"(\\S+) "*numLeft}#{Regexp.escape(target)}#{" (\\S+)"*numRight}/i`. Also, your `def` does not return any value.

Comment: Why `return true if matches`? I guess you need the string matched, use `return text[pattern]`. Your edit is based on my code, but you changed it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces doubled around the first `(\\S+)`:

```
regex += " (\\S+) " * numLeft
          ^
```

When you double it, this part looks like `" (\\S+)  (\\S+) "` - there are 2 spaces between `(\\S+)`s.

So, in your case, just use

```
def checkWords(target, text, numLeft = 2, numRight = 2)
    text[/#{"(\\S+) "*numLeft}#{Regexp.escape(target)}#{" (\\S+)"*numRight}/i]
end
puts checkWords('start', 'In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory.')
```

See [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/iMF9yC)

It might be a good idea to add `+` after the spaces next to `(\S+)`. And if you do not need the captures, remove the parentheses from around `\S+`.

Comment: I have tried it also without the spacing. It still does not return matches

Comment: I have a demo link in my answer, it tells me it works well. Please show me a fiddle that does not work for you. Explain what you need to achieve.

Comment: It is not working for me. Maybe because my tested target is target £10,500?

Comment: Ok, I see. The `,` is punctuation. I have added a simple fix for your code.

Comment: But you did not use my code, and your `def` still does not return any value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  “your `def` still does not return any value”—this is Ruby question, BTW. One should not use `return` keyword to return a value from ruby method.

Comment: You right,  [*Is it good style to explicitly return in Ruby?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023146/is-it-good-style-to-explicitly-return-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

```
▶ input[/(\S+\s+){,2}start(\s+\S+){,2}/i]
#⇒ "at the start of the"
```

more generic:

```
▶ target = 'start'
▶ input[/(\S+\s+){,2}#{Regexp.escape target}(\s+\S+){,2}/i]
#⇒ "at the start of the"
```

To handle a punctuation after the `target`:

```
▶ target = 'start'
▶ input[/(\S+\s+){,2}#{Regexp.escape target}\p{P}?(\s+\S+){,2}/i]
#⇒ "at the start of the"
```

Your function might look like:

```
def checkWords(target, text, numLeft = 2, numRight = 2)
  text =~ /(\S+\s+){,#{numLeft}}#{Regexp.escape target}\p{P}?(\s+\S+){,#{numRight}}/i
end
```

Comment: BTW, this will not get the 2 words if the search word is followed with punctuation.

Comment: Then you should probably accept any other answer. I will leave this one intact, since for everybody else it works pretty fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you're looking at, I think you might be better served by splitting the text on non-word characters and then searching through the splits for your target word. Once you've found it, it's very easy to take the appropriate slices of the array of words in order to get the results you want.

For example:

```
def check_words(target, text, num_left = 2, num_right = 2)
  # Split the text using the regex /\W+/ (matches non-word characters)
  words = text.split /\W+/
  # Iterate over the words in the array
  # Enumerable#each_with_index includes the index, so retrieving the surrounding
  # words is a snap
  words.each_with_index do |word, index|
    if word == target
      # Make a hash with two Symbol keys and small
      # arrays containing the desired words
      return {
        before: words.slice(index - num_left, num_left),
        after: words.slice(index, num_right)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

This can then be called like so:

```
check_words('start', text)
```

And it returns a Hash containing the `num_left` words before and the `num_right` words after the keyword:

```
{:before=>["at", "the"], :after=>["start", "of"]}
```

The `{before: ...}` syntax is Ruby 2 for `{:before => ...}`; either syntax will work fine.

Also, you may be interested in the Ruby documentation for [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html), if you've not seen it already.

Comment: Useful and interesting but I guess this would be a problem if I am also interested in including digits.

Comment: @Vas Nope! The non-word characters do not include digits, so digits should be fine. Further, because non-word characters _do_ include punctuation, this will work correctly with punctuation present as well.

Comment: Are currency symbols also included?

Comment: `\W` matches a dot,  comma, etc. and the currency symbol. The `\W` will split your `£10,500` into 3 parts.

Comment: @Vas Of course, you can use any regex you please for the split---just make it match only things you don't want treated as parts of output words.